# Mapping coordinates to the world map and labeling them

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have a dataframe with three columns: city_name, longitude, latitude. Using ggplot I am attempting to visualize the data using longitude and latitude as coordinates, which represent the given city. I also want to label each point with the city name. Unfortunately the scale isn't quite right, so the points are mapped in the right location.

Example data for dataframe:

```
    city_name <- c("Berlin", "Brussels", "Paris")
    longitude <- c("13.405", "4.3517", "2.3522")
    latitude <- c("52.52", "50.8503", "48.8566")
    df <- data.frame(city_name, longitude, latitude)
```

I am using ggplot2.

```
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50") # create a layer of borders
ggplot(df, aes(x= longitude, y= latitude, label=Name))+
  geom_point() +geom_text(aes(label=city_name),hjust=0, vjust=0) + mapWorld
```

Current result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nToD5.jpg

Expected result would be mapping the coordinates to their correct location.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to stem from the format of your latitude and longitude data.  Instead of quoting each coordinate, just refer to them without quotes.

I also recommend `leaflet` for a wider array of mapping functionality. The code below worked for me:

```
longitude <- c(13.405, 4.3517, 2.3522)
latitude <- c(52.52, 50.8503, 48.8566)
df <- data.frame(city_name, longitude, latitude)
library(leaflet)
df$longitude<-as.numeric(df$longitude)
df$latitude<-as.numeric(df$latitude)
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles()%>% 
  addMarkers(data=df,lng=~longitude,lat=~latitude) %>% 
    setView(10,50,zoom=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of the solution already provided, you might find it helpful to look into the `sf` package which, in my opinion, makes spatial data much more pleasant to work with. For example you can do:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)


mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50") # create a layer of borders

# define data frame ensuring lat and lon are numeric vectors
df <- data.frame(city_name =  c("Berlin", "Brussels", "Paris"),
                 longitude =  c(13.405, 4.3517, 2.3522),
                 latitude = c(52.52, 50.8503, 48.8566))


# convert into an sf object, letting it know the columns we want to use for X and Y
# setting crs = 4326 for lon/lat data and remove = F to stop those columns from being dropped

df_sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords=c('longitude', 'latitude'), crs = 4326, remove = F)

# it plays nicely with ggplot via the 'geom_sf' geom
ggplot(df_sf)+
  mapWorld +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude,label=city_name))
```

You'll notice `sf` objects come with their own 'geometry' column which is recognised and plays nicely with ggplot. One thing to note is be careful with your layer ordering - by adding mapWorld to your ggplot as the last layer, it will appear at the very top of the plot and may cover your points!

[image]